# Issue with locationProvider in Angualrjs 1.3.9 where I still need # to call routes

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess

I been having an issue with locationProvider and routeProvider

In my app.js I have configured both the locationProvider and the routeProvider

In my index.html I configured the base href

here is the code for my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('bergenstem', ['ngRoute']).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.
        when("/",{templateUrl:"partials/list.html"}).
        when("/project",{templateUrl:"partials/test.html"}).
        when("/project2",{templateUrl:"partials/test2.html"}).
        when("/project3",{templateUrl:"partials/test3.html"}).
        when("/project4",{templateUrl:"partials/test4.html"}).
        when("/project5",{templateUrl:"partials/test5.html"}).
        otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});
    }])
```

Here is the index.html setup

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<base href="/bergenstem/" />
```

when I use http://dreamcpu.com/bergenstem/project I get a 404 error

when I use http://dreamcpu.com/bergenstem/#/project it redirects to http://dreamcpu.com/bergenstem/project and the data populates to the ng-view

I created an .htaccess file but it didn't fix the issue

any ideas :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

apparently it took a while for the htaccess file to propagate through so now it works strange was trying to fix this for a few hours before posting the question